# Firefox is aksing me to choose an application when I try to download something, but I can't find any of them - I just find folders

Tags: firefox, directory, downloads

When I click on a link to download something, such as a torrent, I guet a window that asks me to select an application. I want to choose a software on my computer (like transmission), but the only things I can find are folders (.doc, .pdf, .mpd3, etc.).

It does the same when I want to download from the Ubuntu apps directory.

I have checked the other topics related to the same problem, but mine is for every download attempts, not just for torrent files.

Is it a general configuration problem ?

I use Ubuntu 12.04 with firefox browser

Comment: Can you provide a link to a screenshot of your download dialog?

Comment: Gosh I would love to but its a bit complicated to send an image. Is there any tutorial ?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide full path to a binary. For example path to `okular`:

```
/usr/bin/okular
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I get it. 

But still, I have two questions :  What should I choose to download and launch a file from the Ubuntu apps directory, since that I have the same problem ? And why can't I simply save the file on my computer ?

Comment: You can just save it. Firefox asks for an application only if You pressed open the file instead of saving it. And You might also have set it to be the default action in Firefox preferences.

Comment: I have checked, but didn't find it. Could you give me the path to change this option ?

Comment: I'd go to Preferences -> Applications

Comment: Okay, I found it, but the windows doesn't propose me to save for an apt link (https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/biber/). I still need to find an application (apt-get or apturl I presume, but none of them work !). But thanks for the help a lot.

Comment: Oh the biber... It's a single binary file, why don't You just download it from the official website, and put it into `/usr/bin`?

Comment: Yes thanks, it's what I did eventually. But my question was more technical rather than practical. Anyway thanks a lot for all of your answers !

Comment: @Leo: for a technical question about firefox SuperUser is better IMO.